# Can we get infinite antimatter from vacuum?is there infinite antimatter?

Tags: energy, vacuum, antimatter, matter

By doing this?:...

https://www.google.es/amp/phys.org/news/2010-12-theoretical-physics-breakthrough-antimatter-vacuum.amp?client=ms-android-om-lge

Would that mean that there is infinite antimatter that we can "collect"?

Comment: Please note the date of the link, which I have not viewed, but similar searches all show a "breakthrough" almost 7 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Surely we can produce and collect an arbitrary large amount of antimatter. This is nothing new. It costs energy though, so we cannot get it "from nothing". One can convert energy (e.g. a laser beam) into an equal amount of matter and antimatter. To produce a lump of antimatter with the the mass $m$, it would then require an energy $E=2mc^2$, where the $2$ is because we should also take the equal amount of normal matter created into account.

Comment: It costs energy , but it also costs money, lots of it. _According to CERN, it has cost a few hundred million Swiss francs to produce about 1 billionth of a gram (the amount used so far for particle/antiparticle collisions). In comparison, to produce the first atomic weapon, the cost of the Manhattan Project was estimated at $23 billion with inflation during 2007_  From Wikipedia.